# Add item to right-click menu Windows 7 for .jar files

Tags: jar, registry

I'm trying to add a right-click menu item (to run a Powershell script) when I click on .jar files but I can't seem to get it to show up. I have tried two different registry locations and neither have shown my right-click command. Any help on what I'm doing wrong? Below are the two ways I've tried it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.jar\shell\ABC]
@="&ABC"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.jar\shell\ABC\command]
@="<path_to_my_powershell_script> %1"
```

and

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\shell\ABC]
@="&ABC"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\shell\ABC\command]
@="<path_to_my_powershell_script> %1"
```

Again, the issue is not with the script itself (at least not yet), it's with actually getting the command to show up on the right-click menu.

Thanks.